# Using sprees helpers within custom views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I replaced the spree_application.html.erb template file with on of my 
own but I like to use spree's helper methods such as

```
<%= breadcrumbs(@taxon) %> 
<%= flash_messages %>
```

But I receive the following error: 
undefined method `breadcrumbs' for #<#:0xb6525eac> 
What should I do? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be because the breadcrumbs method is in the [taxons_helper](https://github.com/evanwhalen/spree_core/blob/master/app/helpers/taxons_helper.rb) so if you want to use it override the taxons_helper and add the breadcrumbs method to your application controller.